# Nifi, I'm receiving error while adding records to database

Tags: mysql, database, apache-nifi, mysql-connector

I'm trying to load records into database using "PutDatabaseRecord" processor. But an error is coming as "Field Age cannot be null". But i don't have that field either in the records I'm trying to load or there is no such column in the table I have created. Tried many times creating new data and new table. Similar error is coming.[image]

Comment: **How** do you try that?

Comment: Check triggers.

Comment: Try inserting using MySQL workbench so that you can narrow down the troubleshooting approach.

Comment: To expand on @P.Salmon 's comment: You might have a date of birth in your data that is used to calculate an extra field Age in a trigger. If the DOB is null or invalid, the field age ends up null.